# Subversion installation on CentOS 5 - Missing Dependency perl(URI)

Tags: centos, perl, svn, centos-5

Trying to install subversion on CentOS 5 server. "yum install subversion" runs into the prob of

```
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(URI) >= 1.17 is needed by package subversion-1.4.2-4.el5_3.1.i386 (base)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(URI) >= 1.17 is needed by package subversion-1.4.2-4.el5_3.1.x86_64 (base)
```

Looking thru RPM repositories, it looks like there doesn't appear to be perl-URI for CentOS 5... Is there a way to install subversion for CentOS5 that doesn't require perl(URI) - or some other way to install CentOS5?

Answer (score 0):

`perl(URI)` is provided by the `perl-URI` package in the base repo. Most likely it is excluded because your control panel or virtualization solution has `perl-*` packages excluded due to the fact that they interfere with their own packages. Contact your control panel or virtualization solution provider for a fix.